# Angular 2.0 - Meteor UploadFS Error

Tags: meteor, angular2-meteor

I am working on the Angular 2.0-Meteor tutorial and on step 20 "Handling Files with CollectionFS" I am getting an error.

"Cannot find module 'meteor/jalik:ufs'."  I have tried removing and adding jalik:ufs and calling meteor reset but this error seems to persist.

I get the error when trying to run the sample code included before Step 21 as well.

Answer (score 0):

It is related with typings. Right now I don't think there is an existing typings for this package.

So you can write your own typings.

Or use the temporary way to remove the warning:

Remove `import { UploadFS } from 'meteor/jalik:ufs';`. Then add `declare const UploadFS: any;` in any file.

Answer (score 0):

Tutorial was updated in between:

See Point 21.22  Declare meteor/jalik: 
[Link](https://www.angular-meteor.com/tutorials/socially/angular2/handling-files-with-uploadfs)

```
declare module "meteor/jalik:ufs" {
  interface Uploader {
    start: () => void;
  }

  interface UploadFS {
    Uploader: (options: any) => Uploader;
  }

  export var UploadFS;
}
```